# prometheus with k8s pv: Error opening query log file" file=/prometheus/queries.active err="open /prometheus/queries.active: permission denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to start prometheus in pod with persisted volume in k8s.

When i start the pod, I see:

```
  level=info ts=2021-09-12T13:58:13.120Z caller=main.go:390 msg="No time or size retention was set so using the default time retention" duration=15d
level=info ts=2021-09-12T13:58:13.120Z caller=main.go:428 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.29.1, branch=HEAD, revision=dcb07e8eac34b5ea37cd229545000b857f1c1637)"
level=info ts=2021-09-12T13:58:13.120Z caller=main.go:433 build_context="(go=go1.16.7, user=root@364730518a4e, date=20210811-14:48:27)"
level=info ts=2021-09-12T13:58:13.121Z caller=main.go:434 host_details="(Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 10:06:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 prometheus-deployment-7f8fb5f467-wst2l (none))"
level=info ts=2021-09-12T13:58:13.122Z caller=main.go:435 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
level=info ts=2021-09-12T13:58:13.122Z caller=main.go:436 vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
level=error ts=2021-09-12T13:58:13.122Z caller=query_logger.go:87 component=activeQueryTracker msg="Error opening query log file" file=/prometheus/queries.active err="open /prometheus/queries.active: permission denied"
panic: Unable to create mmap-ed active query log
```

I found same issue but it was in docker
[Error opening query log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221155/error-opening-query-log-file-file-prometheus-queries-active-err-open-prometh)

My pod configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: prometheus-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: prometheus-storage-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: prometheus-pv-claim
        - name: prometheus-config-volume
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: prometheus-server-conf
```